# ui view transation from left to right

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am a new ios developer. I want to create an ios app where i want to add two view.At first when app start then first view will show. There will be a button . When tap on button then the second view is show on the screen from left to right and Not full screen but half part on the screen.
How can i do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of viewcontrollers and xib and how to create actions for button? Which XCode you are currently using and for which iOS version you wish to create this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite easy with the help of UIView's animateWithDuration wrapper.  If you are unfamiliar with blocks, this is also an excellent learning opportunity.

First, declare two UIView objects in the .h and define the method you want to hook up to the button:

```
@interface Example : UIViewController
{
    UIView *_view1;
    UIView *_view2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *view1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *view2;
-(IBAction)animateViews:(id)sender;

@end
```

Now in the .m, define your action (notice it's return type changes to void, but it's signature stays the same):

```
#import "Example.h"

@implementation Example
@synthesize view1 = _view1;
@synthesize view2 = _view2;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //alloc and init views, add to view
    self.view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    //Set the background color so we can actually see the views, the first will be grey, the second, black.
    [self.view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkTextColor]];
    //add subview to main view
    [self.view addSubview:self.view1];
    [self.view addSubview:self.view2];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)animateViews:(id)sender {

         /*I absolutely love the UIView animation block, 
 it's possibly the most helpful thing in terms of animation apple could have made.  
 Any property changed inside this block (in this case, the frame property), 
 is automatically animated for the duration you specify.  
 It's even got a built in completion block!  So cool.*/

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 animations:^{
        [self.view1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        [self.view2 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
     }];

}

@end
```

This should animate the frame of the first view to take up half of the screen, and then animate the second view to sort of fly in and take up the other half.  Make sure to hook up that IBAction to a button in a XIB before you run it though.